# Autodeletion of bootup sound

Tags: root-access, audio, bootloader, music

a noob here
My stock rom doesn't have a default boot sound
But my **old** device has a boot sound(Which means I can change it)
Then my question is that how can I set boot up sound on my **relatively newer** device
My phone is **not carrier locked** in any way
My old device is **Samsung tab4 10.1**
My newer device is **Samsung J7 max**
 OS - **5.1.0** and **8.1.0** respectively
 My newer device automatically deletes **PowerOn.ogg** in my **/system/media/audio/ui** after a reboot
 I have theese many magisk modules [image]

[image]

Is any of these modules interfering 
 Any workaround is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to set a bootup (a sound that plays at bootup) sound but my stock rom doesn't have one by default so I can't just change poweron.ogg  in the ui directory under /system/media/audio

Comment: All that I am asking is that my older device running android 5.1.0 Samsung stock rom + twrp is able to change its bootup sound by changing poweron.ogg but in my newer rom 8.1.0 (stock deknoxed debloated + magisk + twrp) is unable to set a bootup sound ( it is deleting poweron.ogg after reboot )

Comment: Please help I am desperate